# Complex SUM in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to do a complex sum with data from multiple table, but i cant figure out how to do.

This is my tables

```
[Article]
ArticleId     Description     NetPurchase
1001          Shoe            500
1002          Box             100

[Product]
ProductId     Description     NetPurchase
3001          Shoe in Box     ?

[ProductArticle]
ProductArticleId     ArticleId     ProductId     Qty
1                    1001          3001          5
2                    1002          3001          2
```

NetPurchase in Product should SUM all articles that belong to product 3001 in ProductArticle. In this example (500*5 + 100*2) = 2700

Explanation: Iwant to to a SQL UPDATE for all rows in Product and it should join ProductArticle to get all related Articles with NetPurchase and multiply with Qty in ProductArticle. It should SUM all this to Product.NetPurchase

Comment: must be one single query ? or can it be a stored procedure ?

Comment: Think i want to do this in a single query, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  a.ProductId, SUM(a.Qty * b.NetPurchase) TotalPurchase
    FROM    ProductArticle a
            INNER JOIN Article b
                ON a.ArticleId = b.ArticleId
    GROUP   BY a.ProductId
)
UPDATE  a
SET     a.NetPurchase = b.TotalPurchase
FROM    Product a
        INNER JOIN records b
            ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f5a0/3)

Comment: @JW웃 - You are still retagging questions :P

Comment: @JW웃 - Yeah your retag is totally valid. I am just writing because I read your previous *about me* section (rollback) :D

Comment: @hims056 I did try to write an answer to bluefeet's post on meta but decided not to post it. We do have our own opinion but I think my opinion will not be welcome there. Anyway I have no grudges around people taking me as an example. I do always have a respect on them `:)`